# Storing a static image on plotly server

Tags: python, plotly

I am curious whether plot.ly (maybe only in the professional license) offers the ability to store a static image (ex. png) on their server publicly, providing a link.

I am aware of

```
import plotly.plotly as py
py.image.save_as({'data': data}, 'our_image_filename.png')
```

but this stores the file locally on my computer. Is there a similar function to store it on their server?

The background to this use case is that I would like to include plots, generated by plot.ly in emails I send.

Comment: here's a good tutorial on creating and sending email reports with python and plotly: https://plot.ly/python/email-reports/

Answer (score 1):

Every plotly graph on the plotly cloud can be viewed as a static image by e.g. appending `.png` to the graph's URL:

https://plot.ly/~etpinard/6929/median-ages-for-females-with-the-25-most-common-names-among-americans-estimated-.png

Comment: @eptinard Thank you for your reply. 
I do not seem to understand the graph's URL format. When I create a graph using py.plot(... , filename = "hello-world") it gets stored at the url https://plot.ly/~accoutName/50/hello-world/ But how can I find out this url? The problem is that the "/50/" portion of the url changes on every request...

Comment: @user695652 - If you save a graph with the same `filename`, it should overwrite the graph at that same URL.